# jenkins on in docker with local build

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I am trying to get jenkins in a docker container to run tests on my host machine. So far, I can't get it to work. I created a jenkins docker image (nothing fancy) and in my docker-compose.yml I try to link a folder on jenkins (/my/tests) to a folder on my host machine (./tests relative path).

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: mike/jenkins
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - ./tests:/my/tests
```

In jenkins I then set the path for executing my test (a .sh script) to /my/tests.

The output is:

```
bash: /my/tests/run_tests.sh: No such file or directory
```

checking in the docker image there is no directory /my/tests nor anything in /var/jenkins_home

I am misunderstanding the file structure possibilities. How can I can get the dockerized jenkins to run the tests that I have on my local machine.

Comment: Can you provide Dockerfile for `mike/jenkins` image. Is `/my/tests` the actual name of the directory you are using or is it under `/var/jenkins_home`? Does `./tests` container this script?

Comment: the docker is really nothing more than FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine ./tests (one level down from dockerfiles and in tests) has the run_tests.sh script.

Comment: Is `/my/tests` under `/var/jenkins_home` or is the real path?

Comment: /my/tests is the real path in the container. Found it thanks to aholbreich tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> checking in the docker image there is no directory /my/tests nor anything in /var/jenkins_home

as designed. You should check in the running container.

1) `docker-compose up` 
2) make sure your contaiener is running. `docker ps`
3) enter container `docker exec contanerId -it bash`, search for folder

[docker-exec explanation](http://alexander.holbreich.org/docker-exec/)

Comment: it is there in the container /my/tests but empty

Comment: @Mike insted of "./tests" you should use "./tests/" . Also try absolute path.

Comment: I fixed this finally as I should have used ../tests as a relative path